# JTree: TreeCellRenderer not doing as expected

Tags: java, swing, fonts, jtree, treecellrenderer

In a nutshell, I want the tree be rendered such that the first level is bold.

```
public class TreeRenderer1 extends DefaultTreeCellRenderer {

@Override
public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value,
        boolean sel, boolean exp, boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus) {
    super.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, value, sel, exp, leaf, row, hasFocus);

    DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)value;

    if (node.getLevel()==1) {
        setFont(getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD));
    }

    return this;
}
}
```

This, however, make all the nodes in my tree bold. What is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reset the font state of the render if the level is NOT `1`...

```
if (node.getLevel()==1) {
    setFont(getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD));
} else {
    setFont(getFont().deriveFont(Font.PLAIN));
}
```

Render's are a shared resource, any changes you make to it are carried onto the next element to be rendered, so you must always make sure you set it to a "default" state at some point

Comment: Work like a charm! sorry it was a dumb question. Did not know setfont needed to be reset

Comment: @GreenMellon It's any one that can sneak up on you if you're not aware of it ;)

Answer (score 2):

In your code you set font bold for level 1 but what about the other levels. Where is the else condition? Can you please try this?

```
@Override
public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value,
        boolean sel, boolean exp, boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus) {
    super.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, value, sel, exp, leaf, row, hasFocus);

    DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)value;

    if (node.getLevel()==1) {
        setFont(getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD));
    } else {
        setFont(getFont().deriveFont(Font.PLAIN));
    }

    return this;
}
}
```